# I18n in Spring boot + Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make a multilanguage application using Spring boot and Thymeleaf.

I made few properties files to save the different messages but I'm only able to display it in my browser language (I tried extensions to change browser locale but they seem to not be working), anyway I wanted to put a button in my website to do this duty (changing the language), but I don't know how or where to find how to manage this.

Gonna show you my config:

## Structure of the project

[image: Structure of the project]

---

## I18n configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class I18nConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

---

## Thymleaf HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    th:with="lang=${#locale.language}" th:lang="${lang}">

<head>
<title>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p th:text="${nombre}"></p>
    <h1 th:text="#{hello.world}">FooBar</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Messages (Properties files)

**messages_en_US.properties**

```
hello.world = Hello people
```

**messages_es.properties**

```
hello.world = Hola gente
```

---

Actually the message is displaying in Spanish, not sure how would I change this, so if you could help me thank you very much.

There's another question that comes to my mind... How would I get the messages from the Database instead from the properties file?

Comment: Stupid question: how are you setting the `Locale`? Have you configured a [`LocaleResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html)? How are you passing it the locale you want?

Comment: I am not, I guess Spring is taking it from browser configuration. Shall I set the locale depending on a button press? Not sure if it would work this way.

Comment: Start at [the top](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-annotation-example)  and keep going. There are 3 things you need 1) a `MessageSource`, 2) a `LocaleResolver` to determine for a particular request, what locale to use, and (optional) 3) a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` so that you can, from a request, set the locale in the `LocaleResolver`.

Comment: No I hadnt configure locale resolver, gonna check the guide that Boris passed me, and I'll update you, thanks again.

Comment: You can also consider [`AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.html) which doesn't store the `Locale` but instead reads it from the `Request`. Up to you...

Comment: I tried the guide you passed me but it doesn't work for me and seems it's due to Thymleaf templates and I'm not using JSPs.

Comment: The template engine doesn't matter - the `MessageSource` does. It decides, using a `LocaleResolver` which locale to use. Are you sure that you have set `ThymeLeaf` to use the Spring `MessageSource` rather that its own?

Comment: Thanks alot Boris, i finally got it working, my problem was that i was not defining MessageSource the right way, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your application should extends **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NerveNetApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NerveNetApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Then on browser you can switch language with param ***lang***
Example: http://localhost:1111/?lang=kh which messages_kh.properites will store the content of Khmer language.

Comment: Being a somewhat older answer, `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is now Depricated. Instead you should use `implements WebMvcConfigurer`. The code in this answer still works as is with the interface replacing the abstract class.